# Changing the signature of EntryPoint opeartion in auto-generated drivers

Tags: q#

It appears that Q# now auto-generates C# drivers from annotations in new versions. When creating a plain command-line project from a VS Code template, we are presented with the following operation:

```
@EntryPoint()
operation HelloQ() : Unit {
    Message("Hello quantum world!");
}
```

However, for many quantum experiments we would want to return a `Result`. For example:

```
@EntryPoint()
operation HelloQ() : Result {

    mutable state = zero;
    using (qubit = Qubit()) {
        H(qubit);
        set state = M(qubit);
        Reset(qunit);
    }
    return state;

}
```

This does not build, and yields a somewhat enigmatic error code 253. Do I have to update the driver manually? If this is the case I cannot understand why the driver would be maintained as a build artifact. Is the driver schema driven by one of the many json/bson files?

Comment: Could you please include the actual error output you’re getting? Also it looks like there may be some typos in the provided code (e.g. `qunit` should be `qubit`, `zero` should be `Zero`).

Comment: I second @Ryan, after fixing those two errors your code builds and runs successfully for me, so the error output would be very helpful to troubleshoot. You might want to clean the project before building it with the new operation signature, just to be on the safe side.